# Recordset not empty when COUNT = 0

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, recordset

Why is the recordset not empty when COUNT = 0 in a query?

```
mysql_query = _
        ("SELECT " &_
        "COUNT" &_
            "(am_table_logg_id) " &_
        "AS " &_
            "TotalRecords " &_
        "FROM " &_
            "am_table " &_
        "WHERE " &_
            "am_table_logg_id = '" & id & "' ")
```

I have another table with the primary_key id

```
21

67
```

am_table only have id 21 from that table. But all the same the recordSet returns -1 in both cases which indicates there are records.

```
   set recordSet = conn.execute(mysql_query)
   cnt = recordSet("TotalRecords")
   response.write("cnt " & cnt & "<br>")
```

And this outputs

```
1
0
```

which indicates there are 1 occurence of 21 in the table and no occurcence of 67

But the recordSet.RecordCount returns -1 in both cases

```
Response.Write(recordSet.RecordCount & "<br>")
```

output

```
-1
-1
```

according to the documentation -1 indicates that there is a recordset

And before next loop I close the recordset

```
recordSet.Close
set recordSet = nothing
```

I dont understand this? what is missing here? Should I use another curser type for instance?

Comment: `CursorType` doesn't support `RecordCount` which is why it returns `-1`.

Comment: This is because you are using `conn.Execute()` to return the recordset. Read the documentation - *"The returned Recordset object is always a read-only, forward-only cursor"*. Forward-only cursors will always return `-1` because of their very nature. If you want `RecordCount` to work use the `ADODB.Recordset` method `Open()` and use a Keyset cursor to get the behaviour you are expecting. See [Recordset Object (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: If you're using mysql as your database then you'll be us then presumably you're using the MyODBC connector.  I'm not sure that you can change the cursor type with this connector the way you can with an OLEDB connection to SQL Server or JET